# jQuery .html(someHTML) is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a script that makes an ajax request to the server. Then the server returns HTML code. After the request finish, I want to take the HTML code and put it on my site.

The problem that I am having is that the function `.html()` will display the html as text instead of making it an html.

Here is what I have done

```
var postData =
{
    'campaign_id': 1,
    'page_role': 'intro'
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url/to/get/html',
    data: postData,
    dataType: "text",
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings){
        $('#MasterContentViewer').html('<div class="well innerwell">' +
                                            '<h3>Please wait while loading the next page</h3>'+
                                        '</div>');
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){

        alert('Loading content failed! Error Code: ' + jqXHR.status);
    },
    success: function(page){

        $('#MasterTable').removeClass('heightForIFrame');
        $('#MasterContent').removeClass('heightForIFrame');

        $('#MasterContentViewer').html(page);

    }
}).done(function(page) {

    var tags = $("meta[name^='is_system_'],meta[name^='is_attr_']" );

    $.each(tags, function(index, tag){

        var value = $(tag).attr('value');

        var name = $(tag).attr('name').replace('is_attr_', '').replace('is_system_', '');

        $('#attr_' + name + ':input').val( value );
        $('#attr_' + name).not('input').text( value );

        $('.attr_' + name + ':input').val( value );
        $('.attr_' + name ).not('input').text( value );

    });
```

I tried to change the following like

```
$('#MasterContentViewer').html(page);
```

to

```
$('#MasterContentViewer').empty().append(page);
```

which also did not work.

I also tried to change the dataType from "text" to "html" which also did not work.

How can I make the force the page to display html code instead of text?

**UPDATED**

Here is sample of what the user sees on the screen

```
<strong>Store Name: </strong><span class="attr_storename"></span> </div> <div class="scripter_header_label"> <strong>Store Number: </strong><span class="attr_alt_id_1"></span>
```

Comment: Have you checked if the response that you're recieving is an HTML string instead of rendered HTML ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly but my page show the html tags for the user instead of rendering the html

Comment: Could you post the value that you receive in your `page` variable ?

Comment: I just updated my question. will the server need to add a header to the response?

Comment: Does the response contain `<`'s or `&gt;`'s?

Comment: Your server is probably encoding the HTML in some way.  Have you checked to see what response you're actually getting?

Comment: @DFriend I tried that before posting my question please read my question

Comment: @Stryner thank you for your comment as that is what helped me fix the problem. my response had &gt; instead of <. after changed the &gt; to < everything worked! If you post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [`.html(string)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) is appending elements as text, then that means that the elements are already HTML Encoded (e.g., `<`'s are in the string as `&gt;`'s). jQuery will only encode html if you tell it to by using [`.text(string)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) instead of `html(string)`.

Two possible solutions are:

1. Modify your server-side code to send non-encoded HTML
2. [HTML Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery) the string using Javascript (I would not recommend this method, however, because it caters to HTML Injection attacks).